# SHINY R Error: Unhandled Exception: Internal Server Error

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to deploy my Shiny App online. However, I seemed to face the error, as shown in the output below.

Hope someone can help me!

> ... [2019-04-20T18:54:07.158806848+0000] Copying file
>   packrat/desc/stringi [2019-04-20T18:54:07.162002079+0000] Copying file
>   packrat/desc/shinyWidgets [2019-04-20T18:54:07.165126424+0000] Copying
>   file packrat/desc/bit################################# End Task Log
>
> ###########################  Error: Unhandled Exception: Internal Server Error Execution halted

Comment: This happens to me sometimes, and it's a simple matter of retrying. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That’s an extremely generic error message. Please show a [mcve] of your app, as small as possible, that reproduces the problem.